# For what conditions of $a$ and $b$, it follows that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln^a x}{x^b}=0 $?

Tags: limits, logarithms

So the elemental limit

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x}=0 $$

Makes it possible to know that for any $b \ge1$ the following limit follows: 
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^b}=0 $$

However, what are the universal conditions for $a$, $b$ such that the limit
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln^a x}{x^b}=0 $$
Holds true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you say "$b>2$"?  Why not "$b \geq 1$"?

Answer (score 1):

$b > 0$, no condition on $a$.  Consider that 
$$ \frac{\ln^a x}{x^b} = \left( \frac{\ln^{a/b} x}{x} \right)^b = \left( \frac{\ln x}{x^{b/a}} \right)^a  \text{.}  $$

Comment: So the problem can be reduced to prove that $\frac{\ln x}{x^p} \to 0$ as $x \to\infty$, for any $p$. Any ideas without L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @NotAMathematician: the problem can be reduced to $(\log x) /x\to 0$ which you consider elemental. Just note that $(\log x) /x^b=(\log t) /bt$ where $t=x^b\to\infty$.

Comment: @NotAMathematician : The middle expression is not present just to be pretty.  What happens when $a<0$?  The reduction you write doesn't quite get you there...  Of course, for large $x$, $1/(x \ln^{|a|/b} x)$ does what you want.